# How to get the original file object in image upload

Tags: material-ui, react-hooks, image-upload

For `antd` image upload from [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-goldberg-yyyvz?file=/index.js) example. i am able to get the `info.file.originFileObj` in onchange function. which i can further send to the api call. same thing i am doing for material ui. i didn't find any particular image upload component from documentation. but from [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-file-input-with-validation-forked-vopy3?file=/src/components/CustomImageInput.js) example, i am getting the converted base 64 image object in `handleImageChange`. which is not working while i send that object to the api. as i need the `original file object` and not the converted base64 string object. can anyone help how to achieve this ?

i need to rectify this function

```
handleImageChange(e) {
// e.preventDefault();
let reader = new FileReader();
let file = e.target.files[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
if (file) {
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      file: e.target.result,
      imagePreviewUrl: e.target.result
    });
    this.props.setFieldValue(this.props.field.name, e.target.result);
    console.log(e.target.result);
  };
 }
}
```

Comment: What's `original file object`? Isn't that the `e.target.files[0]`?

Comment: @bertdida No. Both are different. i have given consoles in both.

Comment: Yea, what I don't understand is - why would you pass `e.target.result` to `setFieldValue` instead of `file`?

Comment: I tried doing that but then the file object is coming empty.

Comment: Hey @bertdida you were right. the problem was in the `setfieldvalue`. i got the original file object now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice! Glad you solved the issue :)